# xcrun Unable to copy to /var/folders

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm getting errors when trying to run /usr/bin/xcrun

```
 /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication /Users/xxxx/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/BEAM-IOS0-JOB1/archive.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app -o /Users/xxxxx/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/BEAM-IOS0-JOB1/MyApp.ipa --sign "iPhone Distribution: MyComp" --embed /Users/xxxx/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision
```

and error is like this:

```
error: Unable to copy '/Users/xxxxx/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision' 

to    '/var/folders/1t/pgh7fy550vl8nrvtmqhvn_780000gn/T/cjftmH0k7i/Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision'
```

Any idea?
What's wrong with this case?

Comment: Did you find any solution. I am also having the same problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provisioning file has been already embedded in your application (MyApp.app)
You can check this by extracting the .app using Archive Utility.

Remove the part `--embed /Users/xxxx/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision` from the command line and try again.